# Xcode - Show database table value in text field

Tags: mysql, objective-c, database, xcode

I am running a phpmyadmin database and have made a table with 3 columns. Username, Password and Age. In Xcode ive made a login app that uses the username and password to login with

```
    NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithformat:@"http://localhost/database/login.php?username=%@&password=%@", usernamefield.text, passwordtextfield.text];

NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

if ([strResult isEqualToString:@"1"])
```

This code works fine!
Is it then possible to show the third column in the database (AGE) in a text label when pressing login? so the Age of the user logged in will be displayed in a text label at the top bar of the app?

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot that you could do to improve the security (not sending the password as a parameter of a GET request, it might (will) end up on some log somewhere unprotected), reliability (your script might not be the only thing that need to run on localhost) or the responsiveness (not doing a synchronous call) of that code.

But, starting with that code as a minimalistic starting point, you could configure your php script to respond with the age value and dispatch this value to a textfield/window title/whatever you want.
But then how to check if the user is correctly connected? Your script running on localhost could respond with bad authentication with a string.

For example:

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithformat:@"http://localhost/database/login.php?username=%@&password=%@", usernamefield.text, passwordtextfield.text];

NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

if ([strResult isEqualToString:@"auth_error"]){
    // do something
} else {
    [window setTitle:strResult]
}
```

But that's really a start.
After that, you might be interested to use [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) to answer the request and then read it with [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html), making your script a little more reliable and RESTful.